# How can I run an executable using python script, giving a .dat file as input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Hi I'm just starting to use python scripts to run executable files. What I basically want to do is use python to edit a **input.dat** file and run an executable **myfile** which takes **input.dat** as the input parameters and saves the results from the output **result.dat** file somewhere and runs this entire in a loop for varying **input.dat**

I've figured out the editing part, but the running and taking input part is what I can't seem to figure out.

On the terminal it would look like

```
sudo ./myfile < input.dat
```

Comment: You can launch an executable by using Python to run something in the command line (or whatever it's called in Linux), and I guess just use `time.sleep` to make sure the executable has finished processing before reading result.dat

Comment: okay so I tried using subprocess.Popen('pathtomyfile', stdin='pathtoinput.dat', stdout=None) and it seems to work (for now). Trouble is the executable is running in Fortran so I have to explicitly open certain output files as 'writable' in Python (i think)

Comment: I'm not on Linux and have rarely used the subprocess module, so afraid I won't be much help lol. Just keep googling things until you get something working :)

Comment: that's what I'm trying lol. Thanks!

Comment: @insonaria: you need to _open_ the files for the `stdin` and `stdout` - you can't just pass the file name of them. Also check the `subprocess.run()` convenience function; you can see my answer for an example of it's usage.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) to execute the command with input from a file and redirect its output to another file:

```
import subprocess

for filename in 'input.dat', 'otherinput.dat', 'moreinput.dat':
    with open(filename) as infile, open('result_{}'.format(filename), 'w') as outfile:
        result = subprocess.run(['sudo', 'myfile'], stdin=infile, stdout=outfile)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if i was clear in the previous comment, i was actually passing the path and not just the file name! (it does seem to work so far) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @insonaria: well it's easy enough to modify the file names to include the path, or to use `os.path.join()` to construct the full path name before calling `open()` on it.